# Google Cloud Messaging no push notification receive to my device

Tags: android

I followed all from "http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/" I successfully registered my emulator [5554] but cannot receive any notification coming from my local server as stated in tutorial. What did I miss? I used vertrigo as my back-end database.

Using this:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
```

My emulator :

```
google APIs 19
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple cases. You need to debug your application.

1. Send push notification
2. Now go to **eclipse** and click on **LogCat**.
3. Then Go to "**verbose**".
4. Then send a message from your server to device using GCM.
5. After that, go quickly to that **logcat** screen.
6. Now **verbose** screen will be moving rapidly. Copy all text and then paste it inside notepad.
7. Here you can see weather **broadcast receiver** is successfully implemented or not. Broadcast receiver receives system wide broadcast announcements. On arrival of GCM message, android OS announces that it has received a message from server. So, broadcast receiver of your application receives the message and passes that information to your application.

If GCM message arrives at device but there is fault in broadcast receiver then you will see error like given below. Reference: [Android GCM push notification](http://techlovejump.com/android-push-notification-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-google-play-service-library/) tutorial.

```
        12-27 22:55:58.691: D/STATUSBAR-SignalClusterView(450):
        mSeparateMobileGroup=8
        12-27 22:55:59.691: D/STATUSBAR-NetworkController(450): refreshSignalCluster: data=-1 bt=false
        12-27 22:55:59.691: D/STATUSBAR-SignalClusterView(450): mSeparateMobileGroup=8
        12-27 22:55:59.699: D/STATUSBAR-SignalClusterView(450): mSeparateMobileGroup=8
        12-27 22:55:59.699: D/STATUSBAR-SignalClusterView(450): mSeparateMobileGroup=8
        12-27 22:55:59.808: W/AlarmManager(357): FACTORY_ON= 0
        12-27 22:55:59.863: W/GTalkService(22378): [DataMsgMgr] broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED forIntent {
        act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE pkg=com.techlovejump.gcm
    (has extras) }
        12-27 22:55:59.863: W/GTalkService(22378): Receiver package not found, unregister application com.techlovejump.gcm sender
    538861816112
        12-27 22:55:59.886: W/GCM(22378): DIR: /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_APP
        /data/data/com.google.android.gsf
        12-27 22:55:59.996: V/AlarmManager(357): waitForAlarm result :8
        12-27 22:55:59.996: V/AlarmManager(357): ClockReceiver onReceive() ACTION_TIME_TICK
        12-27 22:55:59.996: W/AlarmManager(357): FACTORY_ON= 0
        12-27 22:56:00.003: D/STATUSBAR-Clock(450): onReceive() - ACTION_TIME_TICK
```

If you do not see any logs of GCM message in verbose then message from GCM has not received on your device. There is some problem in registering device on GCM or sending message from server.

Comment: Thank you for answering my questions sir. I have nothing listed on my logcat when sending push from my local server. What should i do to fix this issue. I successfully registered my emulator device.